# I need help fix this Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-events

[This JavaScript](http://www.mediafire.com/?8x6mqy0y2dowv7q) and also [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?g24vt95z0m7jpz7) is messing up and will not display it freezes up when I click the button it doesn't move it just stays there.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function toggleSlideBox(x) {
        if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {  // this line right here needs fixed 
            $(".editBox").slideUp(200);
            $('#'+x).slideDown(300);
        } else {
            $('#'+x).slideUp(300);
        }
}
</script>
```

Here is my website. If you register and go to both [www.lazarusbenson.com/profile.php](http://www.lazarusbenson.com/profile.php) and also [www.lazarusbenson.com/edit_profile.php](http://www.lazarusbenson.com/edit_profile.php) and try  to edit your profile or add a friend it messes up and does work right also my private messaging system is also messing up and keeps sending messages to my self and not the other users.

Comment: How is the function called? Are any JS errors generated?

Comment: how is the button code looks like? or the onClick declaration?

Comment: No errors but it like freezes when i go to click the buttons they dont move at all it stays in one place and does not display the hidden infomation this is on a few of my pages

Comment: This doesn't look like enough information.

Comment: I will see if i can enter the whole script

Comment: Try giving us a demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/. When you say that line needs fixing... what do you mean? it's not firing when it's hidden?

Comment: how is that evaluated? try `var isHidden = $('#myDiv').is(':hidden'); if (isHidden) console.log("hidden");` It does not get a response whatsoever or you get some type of error (i.e., what does firebug say?

Comment: ya its not firing when hidden to show the information

Comment: fire bug says something about this line if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {  getting and error and being undefind

Comment: "fire bug says something about this line " ... WHAT is undefined? x? or what? Also, did you try the code above? i.e., using a hardcoded id that you know it exists? Do you still get the same error?

Comment: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error] if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {

Answer (score 1):

A great fix would be to use .SlideToogle() Instead. This will make sure that the code is nice and simple and will slide an ID/Class Up and Down:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function toggleSlideBox(x) {
            $("#"+x).slideToogle(300);
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '#'+

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function toggleSlideBox(x) {
        if ($(x).is(":hidden")) {  // this line right here needs fixed 
            $(".editBox").slideUp(200);
            $(x).slideDown(300);
        } else {
            $(x).slideUp(300);
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It needs the `'#'+` because `x` is an ID.

Comment: It was a suggestion, because normally people pass the object to the onClick like `onclick="toggleSlideBox(this)"` .

Answer (score 0):

jQuery actually has a toggle function built in.

It's called [jQuery().slideToogle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

So just do

```
function toggleSlideDown(x) {
    $('#'+x).slideToggle(300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your error is:

```
$ is not defined [Break On This Error] if ($('#'+x).is(":hidden")) {
```

which means you are not including jquery correctly in your html. Make sure you add this line in the  (verbatim):

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

If you are, the other option is that you are missing some closing parenthesis or bracket somewhere.

Comment: I recommend not having CAPITAL tags. That's the old HTML.